# Angular2 Typescript component loading tutorial/debugging?

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm using [Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) and working with ES6 modules and imports for the first time and I'm having a hard time understanding them.  I basically started a new project with 'ng new Angular2Facebook' then `ng g component Login'.  That created this structure:

```
dist
  app
    components
       login
node_modules
src
  app
    components
      login
        login.ts
   angular2-facebook.ts
app.ts
```

I finally figured out to use a relative path to the component for importing my own components to avoid compile errors:

```
import {Login} from './components/login/login'; // error
```

Since I no longer get compile errors, I'm pretty sure it's the right place, but the `<login>` in my angular2-facebook view is not getting replaced with the template.  In fact, the generated login.js is not being executed.  If I go to my main app.ts file and import it, still nothing.  If I add this:

```
console.dir(new Login());
```

Then I can see the file is loaded because 'exported class "Login"' is displayed in the console, but still the tags don't get replaced by the template.  Here's Login.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    //templateUrl: 'app/components/login/login.html',
    template: '<h1>LOGIN TEMPLATE</h1>',
    styleUrls: ['app/components/login/login.css'],
    providers: [],
    directives: [],
    pipes: []
})
export class Login {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Login constructor()");
    }
}

console.log('exported class "Login"');
```

And angular2-facebook.ts which is always ran:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Login} from './components/login/login';
import {FacebookTest1} from './components/facebook-test1/facebook-test1';

@Component({
    selector: 'angular2-facebook-app',
    providers: [],
    templateUrl: 'app/angular2-facebook.html',
    directives: [],
    pipes: []
})
export class Angular2FacebookApp {
    defaultMeaning: number = 42;

    meaningOfLife(meaning) {
        return `The meaning of life is ${meaning || this.defaultMeaning}`;
    }
}

console.log('ran angular2-facebook.ts');
```

And angular2-facebook.html which is getting bound by angular, but which doesn't have the login of facebook-test1 tags being replaced:

```
<p>
{{meaningOfLife()}} ({{defaultMeaning}})
</p>

<login>Inside login tags</login>

<facebook-test1>Inside facebook-test1 tags</facebook-test1>
```

What I would really like is some kind of tutorial or book I could read to understand what is going on under the hood so I could debug these things myself, I just don't understand why it wouldn't be using my component.  If I put `<login>Loading...</login>` in the html page instead of the facebook app component and bootstrap it, it displays fine:

```
//bootstrap(Angular2FacebookApp);
bootstrap(Login);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `Login` component to your list of `Directives` in your `Angular2FacebookApp` component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'angular2-facebook-app',
  providers: [],
  templateUrl: 'app/angular2-facebook.html',
  directives: [Login],
  pipes: []
})
```

This tells angular to replace the `<login>` tag with an instance of your component.

Without this angular doesn't know that it needs to replace this tag.

Answer (score 1):

In this link of `Angular2` web https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html# you can see that adding `directives: [...ClassName]` inside of `@Components` for example:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Login} from './components/login/login';
import {FacebookTest1} from './components/facebook-test1/facebook-test1';

@Component({
    selector: 'angular2-facebook-app',
    providers: [],
    templateUrl: 'app/angular2-facebook.html',
    directives: [Login],
    pipes: []
})
//Rest of code
```

you can watch the file name `app.appcomponet.ts` for more details, hopefully help.

Comment: I think you need only bootstrap(Angular2FacebookApp); now